# Highcharts: when exporting, unselected series should not show in the legend

Tags: highcharts, export, legend

In highcharts, series can be selected/unselected by clicking on their names in the legend.
If I have some series unselected (they are greyed in the legend), the export function will create an image where the unselected series name are visible.

How can I make the unselected series names **not visible in the legend** when I export them to a graphic?

Comment: Could you recreate your exmplae in the jsfiddle.net ? Because my examples (from post below) works well.

Answer (score 0):

The example (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) works as you expect, when you hide i.e Tokyo serie and export to png/jpeg etc, serie is not visible.

Comment: the series is not visible, but its name is still here in the legend (in gray)

Comment: unfortunaltey this kind of solutons is not available, so you can try to remove svg element during export.